# How can I arrange the columns of a transposed matrix in an special way?

Tags: matrix

How can I do the below process on a matrix in a straightforward way:

Firstly, change the rows with columns and secondly, arrange the columns of the matrix in a way that for a N*N matrix, the first column changes its position with the N'th column, the second column changes its position with the (N-1)'th and so on.

Answer (score 6):

`Reverse[matrix, 2]` flips the columns; `Reverse[matrix]` flips the rows

```
M = {{a, b}, {c, d}};

Reverse[Transpose[M], 2]
(* {{c, a}, {d, b}} *)
```

Comment: `Transpose @ Reverse @ M` is another possibility